# How to remove duplicates from list wile preserving the word case?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to remove duplicates from the below list while preserving the word case?

```
lst = ['AWS Certification', 'AWS certification', 'AWS Certified Solutions Architect']
```

I could do something like,

```
list(dict.fromkeys([item.casefold() for item in lst]))
# returns
['aws certification', 'aws certified solutions architect']
```

But this will lower case all words which is not what I need.

Looking for any one line code?

Comment: If there are duplicates with different cases, how do you know which one you should keep?  Or does it not matter?

Comment: @0x5453 It does not matter for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can map the casefold to the original values and then pull them out:

```
>>> list({i.casefold(): i for i in lst}.values())
['AWS certification', 'AWS Certified Solutions Architect']
```

This will keep the last variant of each duplicate from the original list, since each new occurrence will override the previous one in the dict.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually create a `dict` of `string : index` pairs, and then use it to get back the original words:

```
lst = ['AWS Certification', 'AWS certification', 'AWS Certified Solutions Architect']

res = [lst[j] for j in {item.casefold() : i for i, item in enumerate(lst)}.values()]

print(res)
```

Output:

```
['AWS certification', 'AWS Certified Solutions Architect']
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a dict with format `casefolded : normal` then take values as keys are unique:

```py
lst = ['AWS Certification', 'AWS certification', 'AWS Certified Solutions Architect']

lst = list({j.casefold() : j for j in lst}.values())
print(lst)
# returns
['AWS certification', 'AWS Certified Solutions Architect']
```